# Closing a named file descriptor

Tags: bash, file-descriptor

I created a named file descriptor like that

```
exec {gui_outfd}<>$gui_outpipe
```

now I want to close it:

```
exec {gui_outfd}>&-
```

This yields

```
./game.sh: line 338: read: 14: invalid file descriptor: Bad file descriptor
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT** lines 330-357 in my script:

```
run_gui & gui_pid=$!
run_ai1 & ai1_pid=$!
exec {gui_outfd}>&-
while true; do
    echo "Started the loop"
    while true; do
        eval $(isalive2 $gui_pid $ai1_pid)
        read -u $ai1_outfd line || echo "Nothing read"
        if [[ $line ]]; then # line 338
            echo "Piping to GUI $line"
            echo "$line" >&$gui_infd
            if [[ "$line" == "END_TURN" ]]; then
                break
            fi
        fi
    done
    echo TURNCHANGED
    while true; do
        read -u $gui_outfd line || echo "nothing read"
        if [[ $line ]]; then
            echo "Piping to AI $line"
            echo "$line" >&$ai1_infd
            if [[ "$line" == "END_TURN" ]]; then
                break
            fi
        fi
    done
done
```

And the called functions:

```
run_gui()
{
    exec "$GAME_BIN" $args <&$gui_infd >&$gui_outfd
}

run_ai1()
{
    exec "$ai1" <&$ai1_infd >&$ai1_outfd
}
```

Comment: It looks more like a process is trying to read from the descriptor after you close it rather than a problem with the closing itself.

Comment: @chepner 
 
Yes, but the file descriptor should be still open by the `run_gui` subprocess, since it's a subshell... See the updated OP

Comment: However, I think @chepner is very likely right: just because the FD in question is still open in the "$GAME_BIN" process does not mean it is still open in the shell that is trying to read from it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The combination of ...

> ```
> exec {gui_outfd}>&-
> ```

... followed without further redirections or modifications of `$gui_outfd` by ...

> ```
> read -u $gui_outfd line || echo "nothing read"
> ```

... is doomed to fail exactly as you describe it does.

Once a process closes a file descriptor, the process cannot thereafter use that FD except after associating it with a new open file description.  That has nothing whatever to do with any other processes that may have the same file open, or with what such processes' relationships may be with the one that closed its FD.

Don't close the FD until you're done with it.

Comment: But I'm closing it only for writing, not for reading. I want to be able to read it, but I want a broken pipe, when the GUI process exits. How can I achieve it?

Comment: @marmistrz, you have a misunderstanding.  A file is either open or closed.  If it is open then it may be that it permits only reading or only writing or both, but you can't half close it.  There is no functional difference between `{gui_outfd}>&-` and `{gui_outfd}<&-`.  If you want a pipe between two processes, then perhaps you should consider the shell's built-in pipe operator, `|`.

Comment: Network Pipes permit closing writing while still awaiting to read of results from the pipeline (input).  They call it 'shutdown()' rather than 'close()' though,  See `man 2 shutdown`.   In fact many network protocols even depend on this to work correctly, as services wait on EOI, before sending the final result, and closing their end.    It probably just does not translate to normal files closure.

Comment: Yeap.  BASH has no concept of network socket 'shutdown()'  :-(